# tableview - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone

I'v just got this error in my app.

```
2010-04-06 03:58:55.505 EasyPay DPS[6530:207] *** -[NTItems tableView]: 
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x397af90

2010-04-06 03:58:55.515 EasyPay DPS[6530:207] *** 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
 '*** -[NTItems tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x397af90'
```

This error is extremely unuseful - where do I start in my code?

Here's the stack:

```
2010-04-06 03:58:55.522 EasyPay DPS[6530:207] Stack: (
29283419,
2541614345,
29665339,
29234806,
29087426,
14309,
3233602,
3226942,
3269216,
3265242,
3271699,
3252934,
3274087,
3252583,
12030,
3029574,
3012740,
266666,
29067968,
29064264,
37373461,
37373658,
2756527,
9456,
9310
)

#0  0x01c20004 in ___TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION___ ()
#1  0x977df509 in objc_exception_throw ()
#2  0x01c4a83b in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#3  0x01be1676 in ___forwarding___ ()
#4  0x01bbd6c2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#5  0x00003809 in -[NTItems viewDidLoad] (self=0x3965490, _cmd=0x15ee1bc)   at /Users/shamilnunhuck/Documents/EasyPay DPS/Classes/NTItems.m:38
#6  0x00315742 in -[UIViewController view] ()
#7  0x00313d3e in -[UIViewController contentScrollView] ()
#8  0x0031e260 in -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] ()
#9  0x0031d2da in -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] ()
#10 0x0031ec13 in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#11 0x0031a2c6 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
#12 0x0031f567 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#13 0x0031a167 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] ()
#14 0x00002f22 in -[RootViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x391f1d0, _cmd=0x15e67b4, tableView=0x4071c00, indexPath=0x3977540 at /Users/shamilnunhuck/Documents/EasyPay DPS/Classes/RootViewController.m:167
#15 0x002e3a46 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] ()
#16 0x002df884 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#17 0x000411aa in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#18 0x01bb8ac0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#19 0x01bb7c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#20 0x023a4615 in GSEventRunModal ()
#21 0x023a46da in GSEventRun ()
#22 0x002a0faf in UIApplicationMain ()
#23 0x00002514 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffefb8) at /Users/shamilnunhuck/Documents/EasyPay DPS/main.m:14
```

Comment: If you're running in the debugger, type bt in the console for a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `viewDidLoad` on line 38.

Double-check method names, receiver names, etc.

Comment: For some reason I added another UISearchBar. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tableView property or method to NTItems before calling it, or derive from UITableViewController so the method is defined for you.